# Any way to extend or modify drag-and-drop in Outlook with VSTO?

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I have an add-in I'm working on in Outlook that relies on drag-and-drop to save an Outlook file to a file automagically. The problem is that the default behaviour is to use the email's subject line as the filename, and emails with extremely long subject lines send an error as there's not enough space in 250 characters to store all of it plus the rest of the path.

I'd like to change Outlook's drag and drop to Explorer so that the default filename is kept to the subject line cut to say 100 characters. Any pointers on where I'd go about doing this?

Comment: Can you give us some more information on what you are doing in your addin as a Mailitem has a SaveAs command and you can select your own filename

Comment: The idea of this addon is to promote sharing of Outlook emails by sorta placing them in a specific folder; nobody seems to want to do a file -> save-as. Essentially, a pane comes up with explorer embedded in it, and the user can drag and drop emails right into the folder. This is all done at a pretty high level; I've not touched Mailitem at all, and have totally relied on the built-in drag-and drop stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think you have a couple of ways to do this.

1. run you own pane in outlook and on the drop and look at the selection and do a saveAs on each item.
2. use some winapi to intercept the save ans change the name(i am not sure if this is possible)